# How can you restore an Azure VM Backup to a different data center?

Tags: azure

I recently started using Azure Recovery Services vault to backup our Azure VMs.

It worked so well that I'm considering using it to clone existing VMs to save myself setup time when I need a new one.

However, I cannot figure out how to restore a backup to a different data center.

When you use the UI to perform a restore, you are given an option to pick a Resource Group, Virtual Network, Subnet, and Storage account, but the data center stays the same as the one where the VM was backed up.

I've looked at the Powershell commands for Recovery Services Vaults but I have not discovered a way to specify the data center.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Is your backup vault in geo-replication mode?

Comment: yes, geo-replicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the introduction of Cross-Region Restore (CRR) you can restore your Azure VM backed up using Azure backup to a secondary region. Reference URL - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/cross-region-restore-crr-for-azure-virtual-machines-using-azure-backup/

Comment: i saw this. is it still in preview? this will solve several issues for me.

Comment: Yes, it is still in preview. If you've any feedback/idea, please share it on the feedback forum -  https://feedback.azure.com/forums/258995-azure-backup?category_id=341227

Comment: CRR is public now, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/cross-region-restore-of-azure-vms-now-generally-available/

Answer (score 3):

You can only backup/restore VMs within the same datacenter. Best way is to create an image of your VM and copy the generated vhd to a new storage in the secundary datacenter. I like the following approach if you are using ARM:

[How to capture a Windows virtual machine in the Resource Manager deployment model](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-capture-image/)

The good thing about resource explorer is that it generates the .json file necessary to recreate the same environment. You can then use it to redeploy the VM in a new region by basically changing a few variables like vhd, storage path and location.

For classic VMs:

[Capture an image of an Azure Windows virtual machine created with the classic deployment model](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-capture-image/)

Comment: I believe this answer should be updated to reflect the DR scenario (backup can restore to another DC in that event).  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-azure-restore-vms/#restoring-a-vm-during-azure-datacenter-disaster

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to restore the VM from backup to different region.

First restore VM disks from backup using the following MS KB article.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-restore-vms#restore-backed-up-disks

Then move the vhd files of VM from one region storage account different region storage account.(You can do this manually by using Azure Storage explorer tool or by using the AzCopy tool)

After moving, create a VM from storage vhd using below MS KB article.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-automation#restore-an-azure-vm